# hive context doesn't recognize temp table in pyspark - AnalysisException: 'Table not found'

Tags: sql, apache-spark, hive, pyspark

I'm using pyspark (1.6.1) running in local mode.
I have a dataframe from csv file, and I need to add dense_rank() column.
I understood that sqlContext doesn't support window function, but HiveContext does.

```
hiveContext = HiveContext(sc)
df.registerTempTable("visits")
visit_number = hiveContext.sql("select store_number, "
                               "dense_rank() over(partition by store_number order by visit_date) visit_number "
                               "from visits")
```

I'm getting the error: 
AnalysisException: u'Table not found: visits;

after the warning: WARN ObjectStore: Failed to get database default, returning NoSuchObjectException

After reading previous questions, I've tried to change the ConnectionURL in conf/hive_defaults.xml to be the exact location of the hive directory, with no success.

Anyone on this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: **SOLVED** apparently, all I had to do is delete the hiveContext I created and switch the sqlContext from SQLContext to HiveContext. 
creating both of them (sqlContext and hiveContext) in the same python script just didn't work.
The question repeats itself, and I didn't see anywhere the solution. Hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

Result: 
Deleting SQLContext and working only with HiveContext, everything works fine.

Comment: the SQLContext is to collect data, it's like view in from clase for HiveContext

Answer (score 0):

you should create DataFrame before registerTempTable

```
MyDataFrame <- read.df(sqlContext, CsvPath, source = "somthing.csv", header = "true")
```

and after that:

```
registerTempTable(MyDataFrame, "visits")
```

Comment: df is already a dataframe coming from a csv file.

        df = sqlContext.read.load('df.csv',
                              format='com.databricks.spark.csv',
                              header='true',
                              inferSchema='true')